# Creating folder with changing foldername under Ubuntu in Django project

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, deployment, path

I have this code in my project:

```
name = "some-name"
myDir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'first_scrapy\spiders\tmp\{}'.format(name))
```

I am developing on Windows, and this works - it creates a folder with a `name` what I have set. But when I am deploying this code on `Ubuntu 16.04` - this code creates folders with names like `first_scrapy\spiders\tmp\parfums-promo` - path to the folder becomes a folder name.
**How can I avoid that?**

Comment: Paths in Linux have forward slashes, so `first_scrapy/spiders/tmp/{}`.

Comment: how can I make this work both for Windows and Linux?

Comment: see my answer concerning `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unix based paths

In Unix-based systems, the directories in a path are usually **separated with a forward slash (`/`)**. So we can simply rewrite it to:

```
# Unix-based operating systems
name = "some-name"
myDir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'first_scrapy/spiders/tmp/{}'.format(name))
```

## Operating system independent solution

If you however wish to write an application that works accross different operating systems, you can use [**`os.path.join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). For example:

```
# works on "all" operating systems (well, those suported by the os module)
name = "some-name"
myDir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'first_scrapy', 'spiders', 'tmp', name)
```

Providing functionality accross the different operating systems is actually one of the main tasks the `os` module aims to handle.

Comment: seems like that should work, but when my project wants to create that folder I get next error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '...../first_scrapy/spiders/tmp/parfums-promo'` My project has no permissions to create folders? Or how can I understand that? And how can I fix that?

Comment: @Chiefir: well this can mean that the directory does not exists, or that the user that runs the file, has no access to that directory.

Comment: @Chiefir: see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Comment: but I am not creating this folder manually, but with my project code. Should't my project create that directory by itself if it does not exist?

Comment: @Chiefir: no, you need an `os.path.mkdirs` for that https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Comment: is that Linux-specific? cuz on windows the folder was created automatically if not exist.

Comment: @Chiefir: I don't know. I haven't worked with Windows for like 10 years. Personally I find the idea of creating directories automatically *horrible*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of when to use `os.path.join()` for system paths -- in Windows, `\` separates directories. Ubuntu uses `/`.

`os.path.join()` picks the right one so you don't have to.